# I think Metamask gas fee showing has an error. Please have a look!

Tags: metamask

1) This is the 5 Gwei gas price, and the Metamask is showing it well.
[image]

2) This is also 5 Gwei gas price, but the Metamask is showing much expensive ETH on it.
[image]

So, when the second Metamask window pops up, it says there is transaction error, so the transaction can't be processed. These two pop ups are from same action(so from calling same function of the contract) from my DApp. I have no idea why this shows differently with same gas price. Please help me guys!

Comment: Clearly, you have the same `gasPrice=5gwei` but a different `gasLimit` (which is an estimation of the gas computation required for this function). Can you add some more details of the contract function you call ? Depending of the implementation, the `gasLimit` might differ based on the function input parameters.

Comment: Oh my, I was a blind. I saw the different gasLimit because of you. I think this might be the cause of this issue. I'll have a closer look why the different gasLimit has been inputted there. Thanks @GregJeanmart